# Just a Normal Word

Tags: word, english

I am a word you see every day,

I rhyme with conspicuous,

I am an adjective,

I actually sound a bit like the word biscuit,

Just a bit.

I love eating pizza,

Or you can call someone who does that,

Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought I think the word is

> Ubiquitous

I am a word you see every day,

> An everyday word, indeed, but really this is indirectly referring to the meaning of the word "ubiquitous"

I rhyme with conspicuous,

> The "ous" sound at the end gives the rhyme and things that are ubiquitous are often conspicuous too.

I am an adjective,

> Usually used to describe an object or phenomenon

I actually sound a bit like the word biscuit,

> I think this refers to the sounds in the word - the "biq" and the "t" and "s" (sounds like "biscuit", mixed up)

I love eating pizza,
Or you can call someone who does that,
Me.

> In many countries, pizzas are ubiquitous, as are pizza-eaters.

Title

> Ubiquitous means "present, appearing, or found everywhere" which ties in with one idea of the word "normal"

**Previous Answer**

> Promiscuous

Comment: Noice u got it!